# Submit many spark jobs from different clients on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

We are running some python jobs, with Spark 3.3 on kubernetes. Basically, we run ETL jobs via argo-workflows, 120 jobs every day.

All jobs are running in a separate argo workflow, represented by a pod that do the `spark-submit --master kubernetes my-etl.py`, as we want it faster as possible, almost all workflows are executed in // .

This creates a ton of spark application, trying to spawn pods and eating all possible CPUs / memory resource, as data is small, some spark worker pods are leaving a few minutes / seconds.

**We would like to be able to reuse the pods instead of creating them each time.**